# Central simple algebras and semisimple subalgebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $B$ be a central simple algebra over an algebraically closed field $k$, and let $A\subset B$ be a semi-simple $k$-subalgebra. By this I also mean $k$ is central in $A$ as well, and the map $k\to A\to B$ is the identity map onto the center of $B$.

Now we assume that the map $k\to A$ surjects onto the center of $A$. In particular, not only do $A$ and $B$ have the same center, $k$, but their identities match and the map $A\to B$ is unitary and central (i.e. it sends the center of $A$ into the center of $B$).

For instance, the inclusion $M_n(k)\subset M_m(k)$ for $m>n$ via block matrices does not qualify. For $\sum_{i=1}^Nm_i=m$, the inclusion
$$\prod_{i=1}^NM_{m_i}(k)\subseteq M_m(k)$$
does not qualify either. It is a unitary map, but the center of $A$ is $k^N$ while the center of $B$ is $k$.

> If $A\neq k$, do we have $A=B$?

**Remark** As a special case, if we knew that the inclusion of $A$ in $B\simeq M_n(k)=\text{End}_k(k^{\oplus n})$ makes $k^{\oplus n}$ into a simple $A$-module, we could use Burnside's Theorem to conclude $A=B$.

I was guessing the answer is "no", but I can't find an example so I started wondering. I'd appreciate any help very much!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment! No, I'm not asking that: the question you wrote is somewhat different. I am requiring the very map $A\to B$ to induce, first off, a map between the centers, and second, I'm requiring the resulting map $Z(A)\to Z(B)$ to be an isomorphism (in fact the identity since both $A$ and $B$ are $k$-algebras with $k$ central in each). Yes since $k$ is algebraically closed I know $B$ is a matrix algebra. The question is, does $A$ have to be a matrix algebra as well and of the same dimension as $B$?

Comment: In other words the answer should be "yes", $A=B$, if I'm not misunderstanding your comments. Yes I agree: the argument should go as follows at this point. $A$ is also a matrix algebra, and if $A\neq B$ then it cannot be that $Z(A)\to Z(B)$ is an isomorphism, since all the diagonal entries of the nonzero elements in $Z(B)$ are nonzero.

Comment: Ah! Of course! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this one: take $B=M_4(k)$ and
$$
A=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b&0&0\\c&d&0&0\\0&0&a&b\\0&0&c&d\end{pmatrix}\mid a,b,c,d\in k\right\},
$$
i.e. the diagonal embedding of $M_2(k)$ into $M_4(k)$. Then I think $A$ and $B$ are both central and simple with matching centres and units.

Also, I think that $A$ is forced to be simple in your setup, because if it is a product of $n$ central simple algebras then its center will be $k^{\oplus n}$.

Comment: @Jan No, because the second bloc isn’t independent from the first bloc. $A$ is isomorphic to $M_2(k)$ and its center is $k$.

Comment: Yes this works!